# Not able to connect to mysql database when firewall in active mode(Using java code)

Tags: java, mysql

I connect to mysql database with java coding and give input as hostname,user,password.
its able to connect and reterview the data. But when i activated firewall , its not able to connect database.

Comment: Your question belongs more to http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

Your firewall blocks the incoming connection to port 3306. Set-up your firewall to allow connection on that port.

Answer (score 1):

You should configure your firewall to not block the port number used by MySQL for communication (3306 by default) for the application being executed or for connections coming from the machine where you are running your program.